# unable to fetch push notifications from FCM when app is completely closed

Tags: android, push-notification, android-webview, android-manifest, firebase-cloud-messaging

There are 3 states that an app can be in : 
 **1. Foreground.
 2. Background(minimized)
 3. Completely closed( removed from list of active applications)**

This is the way I've done it : 
 1. **Forground/Background ->** 
    onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) is where I get all the messages which I further parse.

2. **Completely closed ->** 
   Intent processInputIntent = getIntent();
   int id  = processInputIntent.get("id"); // I fetch all the parameters this way. 
   This method works if I don't do the following changes in the manifest.

The issue is my app is a complete webview and I need to save the state of the app and so I used 
            **android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">**

Is this the right way of handling things? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What payloads are you sending from your server to fcm endpoint ? is it Notification and Data both ?

Comment: It could be anything, a notification with just a message, a data or notification with data.

Also what I've noticed is that on adding the above mentioned statements to the manifest the OnCreate isn't called when the app is launched from the notification drawer on clicking a notification. The onResume is called now. Before adding that the OnCreate was called.

Comment: and where are you getting this intent ? in onMessageReceived() ?

Comment: I'm getting that intent in the OnCreate() of the MainActivity.

Comment: And MainActivity is root activity for your app ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: <activity android:name="com.wrapperapp.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Hopefully what I deduce is the issue. I would ask you to try my solution and see if it solves this problem for you.

Comment: This answer might help you. Also see it's comments section. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829

Answer (score 1):

So going by the comments. I deduce that the reason you are not getting intent data in activity after adding **android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"** is because the task is being retained by the system and system is not creating a new task so now new **Root Activity**. But according to [FCM Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher by default.
>
> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload
>   (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these
>   cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and
>   the **data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your**
>   **launcher Activity**.

So, I think the solution to this issue is getting **DATA PAYLOAD ONLY** in onMessageReceived(). *And Here is very important info regarding this method.*

**onMessageReceived(**) method will not be called **if the app is in background or killed** and if the message sent **contains DATA and NOTIFICATION payload both**.

When app is not running you will anyway receive notification. But if you want to intercept data via onMessageReceived() then you will have to create a custom app server which will **send only DATA payload** to fcm endpoint.

something like this:

```
 {
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Title" : "Title for Notification",
     "body" : "Notification body can go here",
     "Room" : "Something extra"
   },
 }
```

Let me know if it changes anything for you.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis I have a better understanding of how "AlwaysRetaintask" is affecting my app. I'm okay with not intercepting the data in the onMessageReceived(). Right now since the onCreate() wasn't called because of the "AlwaysRetainTask" I tried a 
getIntent() in the onResume which is called and still the getIntent() doesn't receive anything. </br>
If I disable the "AlwaysRetainTask" the same works and I do get the information after a user clicks on the notification and the app is opened.

Comment: The app isn't relaunching with **AlwaysRetainTask** that's why no intent in extras of **launcher Activity** *(where fcm sends data payload as intent)*. So I think solution really is to use onMessageReceived() or let system kill the task of your app