# When app is closed from Task Swipe it can no longer receives GCM notification [Android]

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I closes my app from `Recently Open` or `Task Swipe` I can no longer receives notifications. But when app is in foreground or background I can receives notifications. I've been looking for solutions but I can't find any solutions.I checked the app information and it seems it is `forced closed`. Is there anyway way to solve this?

**Update**
It seems that it only happens in my ASUS devices, I tested it in my Samsung devices and it works.

Here's my code.

Manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.my.package.utils.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <!-- Receive the actual message -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver> 

 <service android:name="com.my.package.utils.GCMIntentService"
             android:enabled="true"/>
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    Log.e("Test", "onReceive");
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

GCMIntentService

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
 public boolean isIntentServiceRunning = false;
  private String id;
 Notify notifObj;
 Message messageObj;
 String notifType = "";

 public GCMIntentService() {
    super("GCMIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if(!isIntentServiceRunning) {

        isIntentServiceRunning = true;

        Log.i("Notif", "GCM RECEIVER");
        extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        Log.i(TAG, gcm.getMessageType(intent));

        id = extras.getString("id");
        todayCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        context = this;

        try{
            notification_id = Integer.parseInt(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "" + e.toString());
        }
        jsonParser = new JSONParser(context);

        new AsyncAccessNotification().execute();

        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
        keywordList = mySQLiteAdapter.getKeywords();
        categoryIdList = mySQLiteAdapter
                .getEnabledMerchantCategoriesWithFiltering();
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();

        strJson = extras.getString("notification");
        notifObj = jsonParser.parseJSONNotification(strJson);

        messageObj = jsonParser.parseJSONNotificationIntoMessages(strJson);

        Log.e(TAG, "" + strJson);
        messageObj.getType();
        messageObj.getDate();
        messageObj.getNotification_id();
        messageObj.getMessage();

        Log.e("", "MSG DATE: " + messageObj.getDate());

        messageObj.getSubject();
        messageObj.getReference_id();

        // insert into Messages
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
        mySQLiteAdapter.insertNotificationsIntoMessages(messageObj);
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();

        if (Utils.getGeneralAnnNotificationToggles(this) == 1) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + notifObj.getType());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }


                    sendNotification(notifObj.getMessage(),
                            notifObj.getReference_id(),
                            notifObj.getId()); // ONE

            }

        }

        message = notifObj.getMessage();
    }


    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

}


 private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useSilhouette = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
    return useSilhouette ? R.drawable.icon_notif : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}

 // General Notification
private void sendNotification(String msg, int merchant_id, int id) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent contentIntent;

    try {
    if (notifObj.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("ONE")) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Notif Type: " + notifObj.getType());

            Log.i(TAG, "extra merchant: " + merchant_id);

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MerchantDetailsActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.MERCHANT_ID, merchant_id + "");
                resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.CATEGORY_TEXT, "Notifications");
                Log.e("WITH_MERCHANT", "Notification with merchant: "+merchant_id);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                // Adds the back stack
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MerchantDetailsActivity.class);
                // Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                // Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        this)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon())
                        .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                        .setContentTitle("BDO Deals")
                        .setStyle(
                                new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                Notification notif = mBuilder.build();
                notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                mNotificationManager.notify(id, notif);
```

Comment: @AL. I'm using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` like what its said but I still doesn't get any notification

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829) is for FCM, but it may help you in some way (see the comments section). Cheers!

Comment: i tried adding `START_STICKY` but still doesn't work