# Android Receive FCM when app closed like Gmail

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM API push notification for my Android app. When my app is running on foreground and background, it's fine, but when my app is closed, I don't receive any notification from FCM.

I need a solution for this problem, like Gmail app. It can receive notifications when app is closed or killed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829

Answer (score -4):

You need to override `onMessageReceived()` of FCM.

you can read more details : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Naitik: Thank for your answer. I was override onMessageReceived(), and my add active good on foreground and background, but when my app is closed or killed I don't receive notification. Somethings like Gmail can push notifycation when app is closed

Comment: You can check further details at given link at end of the page.