# FCM push notification when app is killed/swiped out

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM cloud messaging and it is working fine when the app is in the background but not killed or when the app is running.
Once the app is stopped or killed from recent apps it doesn't receive any notification.

Even it doesn't receive the old messages once the app is started.

code for onMessageReceived()

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String myCustomKey = data.get("Nick");
        String myCustomKey1 = data.get("Room");
        testNotification(myCustomKey,myCustomKey1);
}

private void testNotification(String message,String title) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sham_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

server side code for sending notification

```
{
    "to" : "token-key",
    "data" : {
        "title":"title",
        "body":"body",
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
```

manifest code for firebase services and notification

```
     <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/narendramodi_icon" />
                android:resource="@drawable/sham_icon" />

             <meta-data
                 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                 android:resource="@color/accent" />

                  <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
                 android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
                     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                 </intent-filter>
             </service>
             <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
                 <intent-filter>
                     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
                 </intent-filter>
             </service>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how you send notification? server or console?

Comment: I am sending notification from server.

Comment: then make sure you did not define time_to_live . if you define then increase its time so you can get notification later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app not receiving Firebase Notification when app is stopped from multi-task tray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504805/android-app-not-receiving-firebase-notification-when-app-is-stopped-from-multi-t)

Comment: @Divyesh I have not defined time_to_live.

Comment: post your fcmmessagerecive code

Comment: I can not post it right now as I don't have my system, will post after 8 PM, can you please be online at that time

Comment: @Divyesh can you please help me out

Comment: post manifest fcm receiver and service code

Comment: @Divyesh please have a look at the manifest file

Comment: add this in fcmmessagingservice intent filter <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/> and also add android:enabled="true" in both service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134666/discussion-between-mithilesh-izardar-and-divyesh).

Comment: Did you guys get a solution? I am facing the same issue. I am sending FCM notification using API  with only data tag and no notification tag

Answer (score 1):

This happens because on some devices system doesn't allow starting apps or app services by other apps, For FCM notifications Google Play services starts your app service if your app has been killed, when they are killed (ex. Xiaomi phones with MIUI).

Answer (score 0):

***Use your app server and FCM server API: Set the data key only. Can be either collapsible or non-collapsible.***

If you are sending the notification from **console**, then use the particular key to send the notification from the **Advanced Option** features.

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
     // Call your NotificationActivity here..
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: notifications sent from the console have `"notification"` key

Comment: I tried sending from postman also with to and data parameter where data contains all the required data and response from FCM is success but not getting in device

Comment: there is no notification key in body only data key (JSONObject) is there

Answer (score 0):

The Android framework advises that apps that have been stopped (not in background) should not be started without explicit user interaction. 
FCM follows this recommendation and thus does not deliver messages to stopped apps. 

For some phones,Once the app is stopped or killed from recent apps, it was completely stopped by the OS. this can save battery but fcm won't work.