# Firebase Push Notification not delivered when app is closed/swiped out but working when app is in background

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am learning cordova and trying to make a simple cordova app which has the push notification service. I am using the plugin [cordova-plugin-firebase][1] for the service. I am sending only data payloads using the php script serverSide.php . I am getting push notifications delivered to my phone if the app is running and even if the app is in the background. But when I close the app I don't receive any push notifications. I have used autostart feature which enables it to start in background but still I am not being able to get the push notification when the app is closed.Are their any listeners for firebaseNotification and on which file do they reside? From the plugin page, I have used the code

```
window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
    console.log(notification);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

and have put in into my js/index.js file. Should I edit something in the MyFirebaseMessagingService.java file which the plugin provides?

This is myserverSide.php file

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', ' my api access key' );


$registrationIds = array( ' registration id of a particular device' );

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message1. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'click_action' => 'FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY',  
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
    ,'time_to_live' => 0 
    ,'priority' => 'high'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);



$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' ); 
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

My js/index.js looks like the following.

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        // I added the below part starts
        cordova.plugins.autoStart.enable();

        window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function(token) {
            // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
            console.log(token);
            alert('token is'+token);
            cordova.plugins.clipboard.copy(token);          
            document.getElementById("token_caps").innerHTML = token;
            document.getElementById("token").innerHTML = token;
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });     


        window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
            console.log(notification);
            //alert(JSON.stringify(notification));
            alert('message is '+notification.message+' title is '+notification.title);
            document.getElementById("fcm_notification").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(notification);

        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }); 

        // I added the above part ends  




    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);


    }
};

app.initialize();
```

My index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                <p id="fcm_notification"> This is for push notification message</p><br><br>
                <p id="token_caps" style="text-transform:uppercase"> This is for token</p><br><br>
                <p id="token" > This is for token</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


  [1
```

]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: is it a xiaomi device

Comment: which device it is? android os version ?

Comment: It is a xiomi note 3. Android version 6.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app not receiving Firebase Notification when app is stopped from multi-task tray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829)

Comment: @GauravBora I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39640339/4625829), from the above post, is applicable to what you're experiencing.

Comment: I had gone through that post. I wanted to know if I am putting the callback function onNotification received in the correct file. I have put it up in js/index.js inside onDeviceReady. So when I close this app the onDeviceReady function is not run. However someone had posted that fcm or gcm has a direct link to the android device and any notification should be received. I was wondering if I should edit some code inside the plugin folder or the android folder