# No push notifications send via FCM on Android API 23 and earlier

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM to send push notification to my Android applications. Generally on devices with API level 24 everything works properly and I'm receiving pushes for three cases:

- application in foreground
- application in background
- application is stopped

When I use exactly the same application on device with API level 23 (Android 6.0.1) then I only receive push messages in two cases:

- application in foreground
- application in background

When application is stopped, then I don't receive any notification and don't see any message on which I can tap.

In both cases payload send to the FCM looks exactly the same:

```
{
    "to": "/topics/user-6800",
    "data": {
        "title":"title_field",
        "alert":"alert_field",
        "action":"s/1132/13397/729",
        "sound":"default",
        "body":"body_field"
    },
    "notification": {
        "title":"title_field",
        "alert":"alert_field",
        "action":"s/1132/13397/729",
        "sound":"default",
        "body":"body_field"
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions what could be the reason of this issue or what need to do to fix it?

Comment: Hi. Are you positive that this happens Android 6.0.1 in general and not device specific? Some devices, regardless of the Android version, may not receive push notifications when their app is stopped. Possibly from the settings or just simply the device. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829). You may find some useful details there. :)

Comment: FCM is tested on all the API versions. Unfortunately some manufacturers disable push notifications trying to save battery. Please check on a different device.