# FCM push notification not received when app is killed/swiped out

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am migrating notification to FCM from GCM. In GCM, I was able to receive notification when app was in foreground, background or killed, but in FCM, I am not able to receive notification when app is not opened/killed by swipe out. Am I missing anything????

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service
        android:name=".Services.ExtendedInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".Services.FcmMessageHandler"           
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

FCMMessageHandler.java

public class FcmMessageHandler extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (message.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d("ABC", "Message data payload: " + message.getData());
    }

sendNotification("test");
}

 private void sendNotification(String message) {

 Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_background))
                //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon))
                .setContentTitle("App")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationNumber /* ID of notification */, notification);

}

private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.ic_notification : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

}

json request body :

```
{
  "notification":{
     "title":"Title",
     "message":"Message.",
     "icon" = "ic_notification",
     "sound" = "default",
     "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
  },
  "data":{
     "title":"Title",
     "message":"Message.",
     "icon" = "ic_notification",
     "sound" = "default"
  },
    "to":"chIFk6ljlfdskfdsifosdifnodsifnsdofindsofindsfoindsifvndsnmdkslakjdn2p",
    "priority":"high"
}
```

Comment: if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) check this condition and do your code according to this

Comment: Which device are you testing on ?

Comment: @Vishnu, samsung S7 mobile & Nexus 5 on emulator

Comment: see this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: 1) Some device from xiaomi,Samsung have autostart manager. and they do not let apps process to be auto started when force killed by swiping from recents. check if your phone has a auto start manager and your app is whitelisted.

2) Also check whether you are not getting mismatch sender Id error on FCM

Comment: @Vishnu, Notifications are received when app is in foreground or background, so senderid proper. Will check about autostart manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app not receiving Firebase Notification when app is stopped from multi-task tray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504805/android-app-not-receiving-firebase-notification-when-app-is-stopped-from-multi-t)

Answer (score 0):

i got you r using massage tag witch r replaced with body tag. change payload in server.

```
{         
"to" : "deviceToken",

"notification" : {
  "body" : "Pass body here",
  "title" : "Title For Notification",
  "icon" : " icon ",
  "sound" : "notification sound here"
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    //intent.putExtra("notification", "noti");
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent);
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text and image
 */
private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    //intent.putExtra("notification", "noti");
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent, imageUrl);
}
```

try this. I am doing it like this. Use NotificationUtils. Below is NotificationUtils code

```
  package com.fourever.imlogistic.Utility;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;

import com.fourever.imlogistic.R;
import com.fourever.imlogistic.misc.Config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;




/**
 * Created by Ravi on 31/03/15.
 */
public class NotificationUtils {

    private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;

    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, Intent intent) {
        showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent, null);
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;


        // notification icon
        final int icon = R.drawable.logo;

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);

        final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

            if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                } else {
                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                }
            }
        } else {
            showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            playNotificationSound();
        }
    }


    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

        //inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle.bigText(message))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
     * the notification tray
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }

    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Use isAppIsInBackground method code. It helps you

Comment: showNotificationMessage method is called from where in your code?, onMessageReceived method is not triggered when app is killed.