# Android app not receiving Firebase Push Notification when application is killed from multi-task tray on some devices like lenovo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push messages to users using firebase, the puh is working fine when the app is running or when its in the background , but when i kill the app using multitask tray, its not receiving the push on some devices ,but on some devices its working flawlessly ,
Seems the app is receiving  the push but not showing it.
I searched SO and found similar problems but with no solution to the problem. 
As my application is heavily dependent on push messages.
Is this any way to implement it?
I am using following code to restart the service but nothing happens.

```
  @Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

   // Log.d(TAG, "TASK REMOVED");
    PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(),
            1001,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyFirebaseMessagingService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, service);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your push request object?

Comment: MyFirebaseMessagingService its automatically manage by firebase you no need to start manually

Comment: @megamind11 you get this issue in lollipo?

Comment: @JdPrajapati  {"data":{"message":Hello,"member_id":"15","push_type":2},"registration_ids":["er3444@34343sdsadsadsadsad213213"]}

Comment: yes, i have fixed...you need to update request object\

Comment: @keyur9779 Yes this issue is with lollipop devices

Comment: @JdPrajapati what changes can you please tell?

Comment: can you show your payload of firebase

Comment: @android_jain  {"data":{"message":"Hello","member_id":"15","push_type":2},"re‌​gistration_ids":["er‌​3444@34343sdsadsadsa‌​dsad213213"]

Comment: your payload is worng

Comment: see i have added new payload, you need to use

Comment: @megamind11 I have faced same issue. you will not find same bug in any other sdk version.
I think that is firebase sdk bug. I am in talk with firebase teamto coform the same.

Comment: @megamind11 If you find any solution let me know, same I will do from my end.

Comment: @megamind11: please send an email to Lenovo to inform them that their devices have this issue. The best solution to this is if Levono provides an update to fix this problem.

Comment: @megamind11 Hi. Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829)?

Comment: @AL. I read that post but there is no solution for this problem.Do you know how whatspp keeps running even when swiped?

Comment: @megamind11 Did you get the solution? I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some manufactures have restricted app to start automatically. So if push comes, our app will not receive that broadcast.

We have to enable **autostart** for our app inorder to work push notification in every case. There may be some settings named "**Autostart**" . Turn on that for our app.

Comment: Hi, Can i do it programmatically?

Comment: I think you can select some manufacturers who has enabled that feature. Compare manufactures from code and prompt to that activity screen of autostart like given below

String manufacturer = "xiaomi";
        if(manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {         Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
{
 "notification" : {
   "body" : "great match!",
   "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
   "icon" : "myicon"
 }
 "data": {
   "message":Hello,
   "member_id":"15",
   "push_type":2
  },
 "re‌​gistration_ids":["er‌​3444@34343sdsadsadsa‌​dsad213213"]
}
```

When app is not available then firebase is trigger default push from notification object, so you need to use notification object by default and data is use for other data.

Comment: Hi, But if i use the notification tag in the payload ,I can access the data part only when the user taps in the notification. Which is a no go in my situation.

Comment: data part is not working when app is not available, you need to use notification tag. what is the issue with notification tag? can you please explain me?

Comment: i am sending messages which i need to store in the internal database.If the user dismisses the notification, the data will not be received by the app and wont be added to the databse.

Comment: megamind you store in server when you r sending  notification and always tack data from  server as part of api

Comment: you will newer lose data if user not clicked notification

Comment: the wierd part is that some devices are recieving the push when killed