# Push FCM Xamarin like WhatsApp background

Tags: xamarin, background, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem on Devices Xiaomi and Lenovo Phones, when i close app from task manager they stop receive GCM messages, the gcm messages receive only at foreground and app on task manager list. How do i to keep app or service running on close at task manager? Obs: samsung phones keep as well on both cases.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293365/not-receiving-gcm-notifications-once-app-is-killed-on-xiaomi-and-lenovo-devices), *Lenovo mobiles are using Background task killer to stop background apps. To hide task killer, untick restrict in application menu*.

Also, as mentioned by @AL. in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/5832311), it may very well be possible that when an app is stopped from multi-task tray in that device, it is actually killing the app, causing the services and other background processes associated with it to also be destroyed. Suggested action is to make use of the [`START_STICKY flag`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).

Another [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640339/5832311) which might help.

> In Xiaomi phones, they whitelist or blacklist an app based on certain criteria. If you download an app and if it is in their whitelist, they'll permit the app to show notifications. If not, you already know what happens. But the good thing is that you can change these settings. Look for an app named Security. If you revoke the right permissions, even WhatsApp will stop showing notifications.