# How can I send notification to various topics?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Please read here:

**Situation:**

`Person A` wants to send notifications to many topics he is a leader of, so one day he wants to send to topic `database` the next day to topic `math` and so on..

`Person B` is another leader, and wants to do the same, send notifications to topic `English` and next day to `French`.

The topics contain various devices registered to these topics.

This is part of the database:

```
{
 "Class" : {
    "push_id_here" : {
          "name" : "English",
          "teachid" : "teacher_id_here"
    },
    "push_id_here1" : {
        "name" : "math",
         "teachid" : "teachers_id_here"
   }
 },
"messages" : {
"-KzuGjz90g8gAjgVG68O" : {
  "message" : "bye",
  "title" : "Good"
  }
}
}
```

In the application it's like this, `Person A` clicks on a list of `items` example(clicks on English) and there is a list of students that are inside  english, then Person A has to send a notification to that list.

What I tried:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.pushNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

console.log('Push notification event triggered');


 var valueObject = event.data.val();


//Create a notification
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title:valueObject.name,
        body: valueObject.text,
        sound: "default"
    },
  };

const options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
};


return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("English", payload, options);
});
```

The above `cloud functions` works but it only sends to `English`. I do not want to write the name of the topic in the function. What I want to do is if `Person A` entered the list of students registered to topics `database`, notification will be sent to those people. If `Person A` entered the list of students registered to topics `Math` notification will be sent to those people. If `Person B` entered the list of students registered to topics `french` notification will be sent to those people and so on..

Comment: the firebase cloud service is completely depend on device_token that you will get when a device register in a project that you defined in your console. and register a user with device id in your DB. then link them according to the topics. then access device_tokens from DB  and send notifications.
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging
will help you.

Comment: @Abhinav okay so I add a tokenid under each `user`. Example I have 3 users, 2 users are in `database class` and third user is in `math class`. Now `Person A` wants to send notification to the 2 users then the next day to the third one, how would I do that?

Comment: retreive the device tocken from db and put a loop to send notification for each person

Comment: or you can make groups inside of firebase and send notification to that group.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group

have a look at this link.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like:

```
['topic1', 'topic2', 'topic3', 'topic4'].map (topic => admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options));
```

Comment: Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange in general, do not use signatures in posts. Your user-card, which is displayed on the bottom right of every post you make, serves that purpose. If you desire for your contact information to be public, then your contact information can be in your profile page, to which your user-card links. Adding a signature to your post, as you did here, is often considered spam. Such signatures also tend to result in the post being more negatively received (i.e. tends to result in people downvoting and/or not upvoting).

Comment: Needs minor edits to the code example, but looks OK overall