# How can I send notifications to every device using Firebase Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Hello... I am making a simple todo app that will be used by my family.

I'm using firebase to store the "todo's", and for now i'm storing the unique key and inside that i'm only storing the todo title (itemName)

I'm trying to send a notification to every member of my family when anything gets changed...

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref(`/todo-list/{key}/{itemName}`).onWrite(event => {
```

I'm following: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js

In that file it says that I need to "Get the list of device notifications tokens"..

```
const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/shopping-list/${key}/notificationTokens`).once('value');
```

I don't understand how I can access those tokens, or if I should create them - and if I should, how?

I'm using no authentication, because this app is private and will only be installed on 5 devices. So when you open the app, you have full read & write permissions from firebase.

How can I send a notification to each member of my family?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be using the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK on each of those five devices. So if you're using Android, you'd follow the instructions to 
[Set Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client). After adding the SDK you can [Access the device registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register), which you then [send to the server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation).

The Cloud Functions sample you're working from assumes that you write the tokens to the Firebase Database from the Android app, from where the Cloud Functions script can then read them and send the notifications.

There is even a handy [web app included in the Cloud Functions sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications/public) you've been following, which does precisely what you need to do in each client. If you are building web clients for your five devices, you can use this sample quite directly, otherwise you will have to translate the logic to the platform that you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the integration of FMC with other Firebase products, but in an FCM normal implementation you can choose to send notifications to `topics`.

Then on the device side, when the app starts, you subscribe it to the topic using the FCM sdk.

In this way you avoid having to deal with managing token ids of the devices. All devices that have subscribed to the topic will receive the messages for that topic.

[Reference dox](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

Comment: like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505629/how-can-i-send-notification-to-various-topics