# Sending Message from Android Device1 to Android Device2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building up a small chat system with Firebase, where I am confused with Cloud Messaging, Real time database and there with Upstream and Downstream message.

What I have is I have a custom authentication and on registration I will be adding the device token to users collection like below.

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

And saved the `deviceToken` like below

```
{
   username: "test",
   password: "test",
   deviceToken: "<<token>>"
}
```

Need some guidance to proceed further. As far I know `Cloud Messaging` is only for push notification. Let me say `Android Device 1` and `Android Device 2` users are online. What should I use now to build up a chat system?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: Thanks! Could you please make me bit clear? Let me say After successful login, I will be showing a list of registered users(u2, u3) with their deviceToken for u1. And u1 needs to send message to u2. So this will be related to Real Time database right ?

Comment: yes, using functions you have to use javascript, so in the script that you write, you read the message that a user wrote in the db and then send it to the user

Comment: Thanks! javascript?? I am using Firebase for Android client

Comment: yes javascript, you add it to android studio check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505629/how-can-i-send-notification-to-various-topics