# Firebase Notification from Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have already read firebase documentation many times, but it does not seem very clear to me.
It's 8 days of work that I can not do this ..

All documentation consists of links that say "go here", "go there", but I can not find anywhere how to send notifications from my application.

The documentation says to make requests to the html-xmpp server, but how?

I also tried with the "cloud functions", I can send notifications, but I can only if I insert the URL in the browser, and with a fixed title and text, in the code of the function.

I apologize for my poor English.
I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly what do you want? Send to notification from Android device to Android device, or server to Android Device?

Comment: What i need, is send notification to topics, or to devices with tokens, something like the firebase console.
I think with a "Payload", i read from the documentation, or something like that.
So, server to Android Device.

Comment: On your server you just send a normal HTTP request with the information and devices you want to send it to, Sending notifications from your app should not be done because anyone can decompile your app and get your keys and compromise your application

Comment: Just look at this link,https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ definitely will help u..is a lot to cover in order to make the notification to work.so just read the blog in the link

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to read that blog and I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

If you will use topic for push, you have to subscribetopic to android app. Call following call in your activity.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("yourtopic");
```

And send push message from fcm console with your topicname.

Comment: I know how to subscribe to a topic, and send messages from console.. but i need to send notification from the android app, with a notification text from an Input Text

Comment: Ok then you have to write a server application and restfull webservice for this. Service will take a message parameter and send message to topic. Android app will call this service and send message from your input. This is not possible via just android app!

https://github.com/hasancse91/Android-Firebase-Notification-With-PHP-Backend

Comment: Yes, i have read this too, but... i don't know how to set up this server application, i need an input to know how to do...
The documentation says also: 
"FCM servers provided by Google.
An app server or other trusted environment such as Cloud Functions for Firebase."
I Think is possibile with firebase servers, but i need to know how ^^

Comment: Which languages do you know?

Comment: This ia an example with php server.
https://github.com/hasancse91/Android-Firebase-Notification-With-PHP-Backend

Comment: I know VB.net.
And Java for android development only.

Comment: @S.Stefano there are many ways to setup a server in basically any language asking how to do it is way too general of a question for SO. Pick a language you are comfortable with, then use google how to setup one. If you have questions during that process then you should ask SO

Comment: @S.Stefano I wanted something like this also maybe a bit complex, you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505629/how-can-i-send-notification-to-various-topics