# How can we create push notification if the child in firebase doesn't exist. (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I am developing an application which will send notification to the user about the task completed by him on daily basis. The user will get 3 notifications in the whole day at specific timings. Notifications will depend upon completion of the tasks which are stored in firebase. I want this notification process to run in the background and there shouldn't be any need to open the application.

I have looked "through firebase push notification" docs on internet but I couldn't find what I am looking for.

Can someone suggest what can I do to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505629/how-can-i-send-notification-to-various-topics

Comment: Firebase can do that! Send some data messages!