# Best practices for creating a heartbeat service

Tags: android

I've created a system that is a web application in which Android devices enrol. It is an EMM system (Enterprise mobility management). I would like to create some sort of heart beat service that calls a web service proving the device is still online and connected to the network. This can then be shown as a green blob on the web application.

I do have a concern.

1) If the system has say 100000 devices enrolled and the heart beat service fires every 5 minutes, would this have an detrimental impact on the server?

i was thinking of creating a BG service that fires the web call and using START_STICKY in case Android kills the service... not sure if that is deprecated now thinking about it.

I could also creat a push notification to restart this service in case the web application has not heard from the device for a while. This is obviously subject to the device not being in Doze.

Does anybody have experience or know best practices for creating a heart beat service or any potential drawbacks i should think about?

i'm not asking for code, more how someone has done it or the best way to do it.

thanks

[EDIT1]
I have found the following link. could this be used to contact the server. i understand fcm has a persistent connection.

[upstream messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream)

Comment: *This is obviously subject to the device not been in Doze* - it is not. High priority FCM messages can be processed even if the device is dozing

Comment: @TimCastelijns I asked question on this last week and placed a bounty on it. It has had over 250 views with no solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451761/firebase-message-with-high-priority-not-waking-device-from-doze-android-6