# FCM background sync failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to get real time notification on Android using FCM. When I try running my app using emulator, notification message appear correctly. but when I try it on real device (xiaomi redmi note 3), the notification doesn't appear. The token always return null, and I get this error:

```
FCM background sync failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
```

I've been to try read all same problem, there are 2 reasons why the problem appears:

1. Device not have Google Play Services
2. No internet connection

but I'm sure that my device have Google Play Services and is connected to internet, but the problem still exists.

How can I solve this problem? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Have you seen the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829)?

Comment: thanks for response. i've been solved this problem btw. the problem appear because my device error sync with google acoount. so i try to re-login my google account and the problem was fix :D

Comment: Cool. You should add that in as an answer and accept it. :) (see [Self Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

Answer (score 1):

i've been solved this problem btw. the problem appear because my device error sync with google acoount. so i try to re-login my google account and make sure that sync google isnt error then the problem was fix :D

Comment: Do you know if there is a method or a way to understand programmatically if the account is synced or if there is any issue with it? I have the same exactly AUTHENTICATION_FAILED error.