# Android: Firebase Message service and google play services

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an android device which runs 5.1.1, and it's rooted. My plan is to implement firebase message service in the application I'm building which should run on the device. But initially It didn't have google play services so I installed in manually with 11.7.44 version. But the problem I'm getting now is, it doesn't get the firebase token still; I'm getting the following message:

```
FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
```

Note that the device is connected to the internet, and also the program runs perfectly on normal android phones.

I'm suspecting whether I should install some other applications in order to run FCM correctly.

any ideas on that?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970285/fcm-background-sync-failed-authentication-failed

Comment: How did you install Google Play Services? Are you sure they are actually working? Try with some apps that uses Google Play Services, like Youtube, Google Maps etc. If you are on custom rom, you need to flash gapps, simple installation Google Play Services from apk file may be not enough