# How to receive fcm notification if the app is force stopped?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a app with FCM (Just use Data payload and set high priority already).

During the test I found that sometimes my device can not receive the message from fcm.

Regardless of app's state (swipe out/killed/force stopped), the message is delivered to the device perfectly when I send the push request to FCM server in a short time after changing the app's state.
But if I waiting for some hours after closing screen, No message can be received.

Is it possible that in os/device level, the messaging service is stopped when the device entering some mode like doze and message delivery is failed?

Is it possible to receive message when the device is deep sleep?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829)

Comment: @AL.  Thanks  a lot

Comment: So, in short... what to do? Your updated answer does not say how to solve it, your original answer says I could use START_STICKY but it is bad.