# Firebase message not received when unity app closed

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android plugin for Unity and trying to receive a data payload from firebase.
Everything works when the app is in the foreground, but nothing is called when the app closes.

[On this discussion](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/25) it seems we can correct that by subclassing

`com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.ListenerService`

but it seems to be for a C++ implementation, and my plugin is in pure Java.

So is there any way I can receive payloads when the app is closed ?

Comment: Since this is for Android, possibly helpful post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829