# Firebase notification not going on some phones when app is killed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am trying to implement FCM in my Android app. On a few phones, the notification is received when the app is in foreground/background/killed. But on some phones, it is only received when the app is in foreground/background. When the app is killed, the onMessageReceived and the launcher getExtra is also not called. I am using both the data and notification object from the API.
Here is my Android code -

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
Log.e("Here", "here");
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
  try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
    sendPushNotification(json);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
}
```

Comment: On which phone not received notification , share mobile configuration

Comment: You can refer this link, It will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Comment: @Raja I have already tried this but it does not work.

Comment: @BineshKumar I didn't get the notification on OnePlus 3T running Android 7.1.1

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829)

Answer (score 1):

> Add BootBroadcastReceiver in Manifest file

```
<receiver
            android:name=".OnBootBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> Create Following Java file. call the FirebaseMessagingReceiveService
>   inside it.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class OnBootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.demo.FirebaseMessagingReceiveService");
        i.setClass(context, FirebaseMessagingReceiveService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is working till Nougat, their is change in oreo regarding broadcast receiver.

Comment: did you check in one plus 3. after the app kills ?

Answer (score 1):

In custom ROM devices when app is killed by user, all services are also killed ,therefore no notifications

In order to overcome this we have to use data notifications

From your server side send data notification like following format:

```
{
 "to" : "your_token",

 "time_to_live" :4500,
 "restricted_package_name":"your_package_name"
 
 
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Sending Notification Body From Data",
     "title": "Notification Title from Data",
     
     
     
 }
 "direct_boot_ok" : true,
 "priority" : "high"

}
```

I tested this solution on devices like MI,One Plus, OPPO and notifications are received even when app is killed/background

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same issue with notification and after researching we discovered that the issue is device specific, different **device manufactures** will have different handling of not only notifications but **other services** too such as VPN.

- Unfortunately its by design by the device manufacture

Killing the App will also kill those services, you will have to **educate end users** that your app doesn't work on a list of devices, the one device that always returns positive results for as is Samsung device.

Cheers.

Comment: There must be a way around this. Because the same device receives notifications from InShorts even when the app is killed.

Comment: Hi, based on your question and description "On a few phones, the notification is received when the app is in foreground/background/killed. But on some phones, it is only received when the app is in foreground/background." that would mean that specific device blocks the push notifications as explained in my answer... If in Shorts you mean while killing the app or few seconds after killing the App that means the process of receiving the notification just completed, killing an app doesn't mean every process or service shuts down instantly. if you find my answer useful do vote it up, cheers.

Comment: There is an app called InShorts. It is able to push notification even when the app is killed.

Comment: Is there any update/solution for this? How facebook and whatsapp is managing it?

Comment: As of Android API 26 and above, you can not start a service unless the app is in foreground.Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793

Answer (score 0):

I have come across similar problem too. Although some sources say that this is an issue of firebase, it more about the manufacturer who does not use Android's native ROM.

In simple words manufactures like One Plus, MI, Oppo, Vivo, etc use customised ROM(rewrite the behaviour of stock Android). So when the app is killed by the user, all its services are also killed hence no notifications. One way to solve this is to make the users change their settings.

Original Article can be found [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793).

Comment: Is there is any solution?

Comment: @DKV no solution as of now. I keep reading on such articles. We just have to wait for these companies to wake up and start developing responsibly.