# Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app is Killed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There's been trending topics about **Firebase Cloud Messaging** that Data Payload message is not fired from `onMessageReceived()` method for some lower-end devices. And it's true. Here is the result:

**App getting killed scenario:**

**Devices got data payload:**

1. Nexus 5X : OS 7.1

---

**Devices didn't get data payload:**

1. Xiaomi MI 4C : OS 5.1
2. Huawei LUA-U22 : OS 5.1

Be ensured that I'm not sending **notification** key from Server/Postman.

I am looking for the solution, I got data payload from Firebase including all types of devices, OS & obviously from API level 15. My Postman details are as follows.

```
 {
    "registration_ids": ["fC5uxGSRCsg:APA91bHh9fMXQ41LpX6tjjSsBKGrKTWYpzKimLDzvBGSHDPo2pq87JHqogUp2kqrmJi06siG_p6DfgRCim23iFzlBQAIrgtMDqRW4s39zUqv9CzyPqzxVl5PtnHPRDs4OagTuTePNyDI"],
    "data": {
        "title" : "my_custom_value",
        "message" : "tekksdasdasdsa",
         "isBackground" : "",
          "payload" : {


          },
           "timestamp" : "",
            "imageUrl" : "",
     }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app not receiving Firebase Notification when app is stopped from multi-task tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504805/android-app-not-receiving-firebase-notification-when-app-is-stopped-from-multi-t)

Answer (score 2):

In some devices Like **MI** you will not receive Notification if the application is **removed** from **application tray**! but you will receive notifications if you **killed an activity** and **haven't removed** from **application tray**!

In Xiaomi phones, they whitelist or blacklist an app based on certain criteria. If you download an app and if it is in their whitelist, they'll permit the app to show notifications.

**How to Test**:-
Try testing your app after killing your app activities rather removing from app tray if that works fine , thats all you could do at your end!

Comment: I know the cause whitelisting process of Xiomi mobile manufacturer. But I need to solve all devices which not get the FCM payload.

Answer (score 1):

According to Firebase documentation:

> You have two options for assigning delivery priority to downstream messages: normal and high priority. Delivery of normal and high priority messages works like this:
>
> **Normal priority.** This is the default priority for **data** messages.
>
> **High priority.** This is the default priority for **notification** messages.

Since you are using **data** payload the notification priority is by default set to normal. Back to the documentation:

> `onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the
>   following exceptions:
>
> **Notification messages:** delivered when your app is in the background. In
>   this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray.
>   A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> **Data messages:** On Android platform, the data message can work on
>   background and foreground. The data message will be handled by
>   `onMessageReceived()`. A platform specific note here would be: On
>   Android, the data payload can be retrieved in the Intent used to
>   launch your activity.
>
> **Messages with both notification and data payload:** Both background and
>   foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>   device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
>   of the intent of your launcher Activity.

I suspect it's related to using the **data** payload. Due to app getting killed for ram management in some devices, `onMessageReceived()` might be skipped. A simple workaround trick would be using both of the **data** and **notification** payload. So that even when If the app is no longer running you'll still get a notification in the system tray. Later handle the notification after getting clicked from the notification tray.

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "message_body",
        "title": "message_title"
    },
    "notification": {
        "body": "message_body",
        "title": "message_title"
    }
}
```

Check the official documentation [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)