# Android: How many times can I send a high priority GCM to my app in Android 7.0?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-doze

I have an android app and I am using GCM. I will upgrade it to FCM. But for now, How many times can I send high priority GCM, or for the sake of it FCM so that it can do some network requests in an hour.

Comment: Down voting must be followed by the reason. It does not help me if you just downvote it without the reason. I want to improve too.

Comment: i agree, i'm struggling to find any clear docs on fcm high priority, e.g. what are conditions for messages to be de-prioritised / how doze and standby modes are interacting with priority / are there any adverse effects of setting high priority to every non-background notification

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Downstream messages, there is no limit on how many messages you could send regardless of it's `priority`.

I noticed that you added the [android-doze](/questions/tagged/android-doze) tag in your question. For some devices, it is possible that some requests will be postponed or dropped until such time that the app exits doze mode, similarly to what happens when the app is in background and/or killed state (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829)).