# What is FCM's stated reliability?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having issues with some users not receiving push notifications of time sensitive information.

Its likely that the issue lies in our implementation but I'm trying to get an idea of what Firebase claims in terms of reliability.

Comment: While this is a fair question, it's really off topic for this site. *Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. Head on over the Firebase google groups for more open ended questions like this. In my 3+ years working with Firebase, they have rarely been down (twice?). Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

FCM is used primarily for push notifications. Push notifications for Android are commonly an additional feature for apps.

FCM sends the message(s) ***as soon as feasible***, however, it is not advised to hold time sensitive info/app critical data, since there are factors that may or may not contribute to the delay that a message is received -- in some cases/devices, the message is not received at all ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829)).

In FCM's defense, it is a free service, used by millions of apps, handling millions of messages at a time. So the behavior of "*sending it as soon as feasible*" is awesome as it is.

If the data you need to send is critical, you might be better off to use [Firebase Real-time Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

Comment: [Some questions can not and should not be answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hi @Rob. Thanks for the feedback. I'm familiar with the link. I decided to go ahead and put in answer since I think it doesn't qualify for the 5 qualities of a *not* well-asked question (it did kinda barely passed the fifth one tho). It is related to programming in a sense that it is asking about the service they used. The topic is also something that might (or probably already has) been asked before by FCM users. I was hoping to use this as a dup/reference post in the future as well. Will tag it as dup if I find an earlier version tho. Cheers!

Comment: The question is off topic about servers, asks for opinions or claims of reliability, questions their implementation but provides no code...I could go on and on but it looks like it will be closed soon anyway.