# Not getting FCM notification when app is completely killed

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I have been trying to send the Push notification using FCM. It works completely when the app is in Foreground or background. But if i kill the app from recent list then i'm not getting any notification.

```
This is my structure of FCM with data payload

{"registration_ids":["here is my FCM token"],
    "data":{
    "body" :"Hello All, Hope you had a great time!",
    "title":"Title",
    "click_action":"ACTIVITY_MESSAGE",
    "sound":"default",
    "type" : "message",
    "message": "message_here",
    "time" : "2016-12-14 03:37:pm"
  }
  } 

This is the structure with data and notification

{"registration_ids":["Here is my FCM token"],
  "notification":{
     "body" : "Hello All, Hope you had a great time!",
     "title":"title here",
     "click_action":"ACTIVITY_HOME",
     "sound":"default"
        },
  "data":{
     "type" : "message",
     "message": "message_here",
     "time" : "2016-12-14 03:37:pm"
}
}
```

I have also tried the same with notification tag and data as well but nothing is working in case whent the app is killed. If any one have any idea how can i get the notification in case of my app is killed then do share.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4247543

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put `"forceStart": "1"` inside the data brackets.
In this way you should force the application to start the notification.