# Suddenly Firebase push notification stop working when App is killed

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our Android app was working fine since last evening. Whenever we are sending notification using fem api, we are getting success, but the notification is not delivered to the desired device. While digging into this issue, we found out that if the app is killed the notification is not working.We have data payload for showing custom image and data in notification.The same code was working fine in our last build as well as the current build.

Comment: [Possibly helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829)

Comment: How do you kill your app? If you force stop it in setting menu, it will also kill the part for receiving the notification.