# Upgrading from GCM to FCM on android app - new service active after force kill of the app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I upgraded from **GCM** to **FCM** and now I'm testing the experience of upgrading users

I have the following steps

1. install the app version that supports **GCM**
2. Upgrade to a new version that supports **FCM**
3. Send push message on **Firebase console**

The problem is that I see the message received on the notification area in the device, but it doesn't invoke the code  `CloudMessagingListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService`
I have a debug log at the beginning of `CloudMessagingListenerService#onMessageReceived`

After I go to the app info and select **force stop** and reopen the app my code inside `CloudMessagingListenerService#onMessageReceived` is called properly.

Any idea what causes this and what can be done to avoid the **force kill** (my users won't do it voluntarily)

*in both scenarios the app is in the background*

**Update:**

The problem is w/ receiving messages from the **Firebase console**.

I added logs in `CloudMessagingListenerService#onCreate` and `CloudMessagingListenerService#onDestroy` and I can see that they are called w/ a 100ms time diff between them - while `CloudMessagingListenerService#onMessageReceived` isn't called so it seems `FirebaseMessagingService` decides to handle the notification but not the data portion

**Regarding messages sent from the server:**
this is the json I send from the server - the data part is propagated correctly to my code, but the notification is ignored, when I check what is the content of `remoteMessage.getNotification()` I get *null*

`{
  "to": "my token",
  "collapse_key": "my app",
  "notification": {
    "title": "server title",
    "body": "server text"
  },
  "data": {
    "tag": "debug",
    "action": "custom-push",
    ...
  }
}`

Comment: Can you share your FCM message body? The one you construct in the server...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app not receiving Firebase Notification when app is stopped from multi-task tray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829)

Comment: @HedeH I'm not posting my server json b/c it is handled ok - as  updated above the problem is w/ messages generated in the _Firebase console_

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Console sends the message in the `notification` key, which means it is only delivered to the `onMessageReceived()` if the app is running in foreground/open. If the app is running in the background the notification will show up on the notification drawer directly.
To receive the payload in `onMessageReceived()` of your class extending `FirebaseMessagingService` make sure the the notification content is passed in the `data` key of your request to the made to the FCM server. This will ensure that the payload is delivered to the `onMessageReceived()` irrespective of whether the app is in foreground/background.

Comment: In the scenarios I'm describing the app is in the background both of the times