# Some Android manufacturer kill FCM yet GCM once swiped away from multi-task tray

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

There are many questions, articles that mentioned some manufacturer kill FCM when swiped app away in the recent apps, like this: [Android app not receiving Firebase Notification when app is stopped from multi-task tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504805/android-app-not-receiving-firebase-notification-when-app-is-stopped-from-multi-t)
However, it doesn't happen with GCM. After swiped app away, the notification from GCM still works properly.
[image]

Like the above image, GCM receiver is still running despite the app has been swiped out.
Unfortunately, GCM is going to be shut down on April 10, 2019.

Can anyone explain the difference between GCM vs FCM? And any suggestions to keep FCM persist

Comment: What kind of device you were using? If this is a device made in China, this will surely not work. Google Services cannot use in China. And Firebase was blocked by GFW in China.

Comment: I'm using Oppo F7. Play services still work if not forced stop